# Separating Alfresco server and postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, alfresco

To separate database PostgreSQL from alfresco, i did these steps with failure:

### 1. step1 : Install PostgreSQL 9.4 in Linux machine 173.16.6.61

### creating database alfresco with owner alfresco:

```
CREATE USER alfresco WITH PASSWORD 'admin';
CREATE DATABASE alfresco WITH OWNER alfresco;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE alfresco TO alfresco;
```

### 2. step2 : Install on Linux machine 173.16.6.66 using the Alfresco Content Services Installer without PostgreSQL.

### change alfresco-global.propertie :

```
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.username=alfresco
db.password=admin
db.name=alfresco
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://173.16.6.61:5432/alfresco
db.pool.max=275
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: It still not working, i miss something  ?

Comment: Did you change postgres to allow remote connections, it doesn't do that by default - the default is to accept local connections only.

Comment: Please share your logs, so we see the error.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was remote connections to PostgreSQL database server:

### Change The Listen Address

```
linux1@fe35577e9f8b:/# vim /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
```

and change :

```
listen_addresses = '*'         # it accepts connection from any IP;
```

### To allow connections from absolutely any address with password authentication:

```
linux1@fe35577e9f8b:/# vim /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf
```

add this line at the end of pg_hba.conf

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. Anyway, you should be more specific on the IPs your postgres is accepting, for security reasons.